# add SplitViewController view trouble under iOS5

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, ios5

When I trying to add SplitViewController to view hierarchy application terminates with:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController initWithContentViewController:] must not be called with `nil`.'

```
SplitViewController *viewController = [[SplitViewController alloc] init];
[self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
```

Where SplitViewController subclass of UISplitViewController

I don't understand which popover it means.
This trouble appear only on iOS5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After initializing viewController, you should set its viewControllers with viewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:**leftNavigationController**, **rightNavigationController**, nil];

Else, your SplitViewController does not know what to display on the left and on the right.

Pay attention also to the delegate.

Please check if this helps :)